# How to show Intimidatetime on page load and display always on page?

Tags: jquery

I need to implement a DateTime picker, with hours, minutes and seconds option along with date, month and year.

I am using this [Intimidatetime](https://github.com/trentrichardson/Intimidatetime), and this works fine the traditional way with textbox and onfocus shows the Date-Time picker.

But I want the DateTimePicker to show always(always display:block).Is it possible to show the datetimepicker always without using a textbox?

Something similar to this [Inline DatePicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#inline)

Here's an a simple page I created:

```
<html>
 <head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" type="text/css" href="http://trentrichardson.com/examples/Intimidatetime/Intimidatetime.css" />
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="http://trentrichardson.com/examples/Intimidatetime/Intimidatetime.js"> 
   </script>
 </head>

 <body>
  <div class="example-container" id="test" style="border: 1px solid green;">
  <input type="text" id="textboxtest" value="" class="inputFull" data-intimidatetime="3" class="selector">
  </div>

  <script>
    $('#textboxtest').intimidatetime({
     previewFormat: 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'
    });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried editing this file [Intimidatetime.js](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/Intimidatetime/Intimidatetime.js) and changed the "display:none" to  "display:block" and it works

```
  inst.$p.css('display','none');
```

But when I try to edit styles from my project JS file its not working.

```
  $("#test").find(".intimidatetime").css("display","block");
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this below line is finding the correct element you want to update the style on?

```
 $("#test").find(".intimidatetime")
```